# Spring Cloud Data Flow Java DSL for Task / Batch

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am wondering if there is any java dsl support for registering spring batch applications as SCDF taks? Till now I was able to find only streams support for Java DSL.

Any link in this direction will be much helpful. Also how to automatically deploy spring batch as SCDF tasks in production environment without any manual intervention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's Java DSL support for Tasks. This was recently introduced in 2.4 as part of the SCDF's IT test-suite, but it is not promoted as part of the SCDF's REST client that we ship as a library — see: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#3949](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3949) / [spring-io/dataflow.spring.io#242](https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/issues/242). Feel free to contribute the migration if you have cycles.

That said, though, we have end-to-end IT tests that leverage this capability [see: [DataFlowIT.java#L771-L906](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/integration/test/DataFlowIT.java#L771-L906)], which we use for each commit based IT test runs internally. You could certainly follow this as a pattern to automate the creation and launch of the task/batch-jobs.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question. Assuming the other automated way of registering the task applications on SCDF will be through REST API. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Correct. The same IT test includes a few sample calls, which you can use as the reference. Also, we follow this pattern extensively in [SCDF Acceptance Tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests). Another reference point.